# How to compare two arrays in protractor cucumber framework

Tags: protractor, cucumberjs

I am using Protractor-Cucumber Framework. I need to compare two arrays when checking the sorting scenario. I have used below code for that comparison.

```
expect(sorted1.toString()).to.equal(unSorted1.toString());
```

but when these stringified arrays are not equal, the protractor will stop the complete execution and it will not execute the below scenarios due to this assertion. The error coming in command prompt is given below.

```
E/launcher - AssertionError: expected 'test cqa,source cqa_test,sep 3
0 reg ref data,rf tp,reg sep 25,reg oct 3,reg ins ln,reg data,ref sep 22 
ln,pa anisha' 
to equal 
'test cqa,source cqa_test,sep 30 reg ref data,rf tp,reg ins ln,reg sep 25,reg 
 oct 3,reg data,ref sep 22 ln,pa anisha'
at D:\automation\features\step_definitions\base_definitions.js:790:46
at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (C:\Users\S1027C\AppData\Roaming\npm\node
_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1376:14)
at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\S1027C\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pro
tractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3084:14)
at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\S1027C\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3067:27)
at asyncRun (C:\Users\S1027C\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\no
de_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2927:27)
at C:\Users\S1027C\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules
\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:668:7
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```

I need to excute full scenarios even this particular one failed. For that how can i modify the assertion. Can anyone help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: it's hard to make guesses without seeing an error stack

Comment: Thanks for your reply...I have added the error stack.

Comment: Have you tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash. There is a method called equals(firstArray, secondArray), which compares content of both the arrays and returns boolean value..?